# Working with Backbone

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, backbone.js

I am a starter in Backbone.js. I have downloaded the BackboneTemplateSpa for MVc 4.0 as suggested by this [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/getting-started-with-backbonejs-in-mvc-4/)

So, Following that I have a full project with me

but I am unable to get it's desciption or documentation.
It's very hard to understand how routers are working and how this whole website is working. How can I start with creating application  with backbone in MVC 4.0 easily?

I have gone through TOdo Sample also. It's way different from this template that I have downloaded.

Also Which is the correct format as This template has it's models defined as .Cs classes where as todo  do not have any cs class for models.
Also The template I have downloaded is having Controllers but todo app is working withoput controllers. I am really confused with backbone in MVC 4.0 . Please help

This is todo app

http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/

Comment: This is a good tutorial for backbone: http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/backbone-js-wine-cellar-tutorial-part-1-getting-started/ . It builds up very wel and also explains the router. No usage with MVC4 though.